# lock('WITH (NOLOCK)') Breaks SQL Query Cache in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

Running a rails 4 application with an MSSQL DB.
I am trying to add a nolock hint to my query, using lock('WITH (NOLOCK)') but this causes the record to be reloaded explicitly. I want to still make use of the SQL query cache and add the nolock hint.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: If you place the updated SQL script into a Stored Procedure, that will be execution plan will be cached

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have a legacy app that has tons of querys that I need this to happen for. Putting them all into stored procs wouldn't cut it.